# App not loading

Tags: ios

I'm using MFP 8.0 , cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017060910 , IONIC 2.2.1

I could able to execute these commands

```
cordova prepare
ionic build ios --mfpwebencrypt.
```

And it gives a resources.zip (IOS platform) folder in my www directory.
But, After this my app resources are not loading.
It stuck in splash screen

How to do this?

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is addressed in upcoming release of MobileFirst Cordova plugin.

You can use following workaround to resolve the issue.

- Replace your project's `AppDelegate.m` file with following file
  https://ibm.box.com/s/wntb2vz4zj00bddfk3qwdjkf4fxgx3kk
- Clean and build your application